# How to do other action with phone number in textview in Android

Tags: android

I add this line to my textview:

```
setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL);
```

And it works fine.
However, I want to check if this is a phone number, when user clicks on this link, it will pop up a dialog and not just make call.
How to do it, please help.

Comment: check this:http://stackoverflow.com/a/2886570/870450

Comment: sorry, i want the link is clickable, but instead of making call, i want to do other action such as show a toast or pop up a dialog.